# Как можно записать данные функции более по питоновски

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

изучаю питон совсем недавно, добрался до библиотеки numpy. возвести элементы матрицы к квадрат не составило труда, но вот возводить в квадрат по условию - проблема. пришлось возвращаться к двойному for чтобы достичь результата.
p.s во второй функции закомментирован кусок, который в принципе возводил в квадрат все четные элементы, но все остальные заменял на 1

```
from pprint import pprint


matrix = np.random.randint(1, 9, (8, 8))

def sqr_elem_matrix(matrix):
    result = np.square(matrix)
    return result

def sqr_even_elem_matrix(matrix):
    for i in range(matrix.shape[0]):
        for j in range(matrix.shape[1]):
            if matrix[i][j] % 2 == 0:
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j] * matrix[i][j]
            else:
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j]
    return matrix
    # result = np.square(matrix, where=[matrix % 2 == 0])
    # return result

def sqr_elem_less5(matrix):
    for i in range(matrix.shape[0]):
        for j in range(matrix.shape[1]):
            if matrix[i][j] < 5:
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j] * matrix[i][j]
            else:
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j]
    return matrix

pprint(matrix)
print(f'(1) - sqr elem matrix\n(2) - sqr even elem matrix\n(3) - sqr elem < 5')
num_task = int(input())
if num_task == 1:
    pprint(sqr_elem_matrix(matrix))
if num_task == 2:
    pprint(sqr_even_elem_matrix(matrix))
if num_task == 3:
    pprint(sqr_elem_less5(matrix))
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам поможет [np.where()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```
def sqr_even_elem_matrix(matrix):
    return np.where(matrix % 2 == 0, matrix ** 2, matrix)

def sqr_elem_less5(matrix):
    return np.where(matrix < 5, matrix ** 2, matrix)
```

Comment: Или так, если dtype=int, matrix=matrix**(2-matrix%2)